# Aspect for methods in extended class does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop

I try to apply aspect for two methods that are in abstract class, that is extended by another class.

Problem is that pointcut i am using doesn't work.

Code looks like this:

```
public class ClassA extends ClassB {

    public void testMethod(String testString, Integer testInt){
        extendedClassMethod1(testString, testInt);
        extendedClassMethod2(testString, testInt);
    }
}

public abstract class ClassB {

   public String extendedClassMethod1(String testString, Integer testInteger) {
        return testString + testString.toString();
    }

    public String extendedClassMethod2(String testString, Integer testInteger) {
        return testString + testString.toString();
    }
}

@Aspect
public class AspectClass {

   @AfterReturning(
            value = "execution(* com.test.ClassB.*(..)) && args(testString, testInteger)",
            returning = "result")
    public void aspectMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, String testString, Integer testInteger, String result){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Goal is to create aspect thay will work when extendedClassMethod1 or extendedClassMethod2 is used in classes (f.e. ClassA) that extends ClassB.

Another thing is that Intellij shows that aspect method should be applied to this two methods, but in runtime it does not.

Comment: you don't apply your aspect to the methods of ClassA, so why should it work?

Comment: I don't need aspect to run for methods in ClassA (shouldn't work for testMethod). I need it to run when extendedClassMethod1 or extendedClassMethod2 from ClassB are used.

Comment: yes, but they will be executed from ClassA, not ClassB. so: you don't apply your aspect to the methods of ClassA ...

Comment: in your ClassA, overwrite the methods and call them by super(testString, testInteger);

Comment: Do you use Spring AOP or AspectJ? If you use Spring AOP then your objects have to be beans. Are they?

Comment: @KenBekov i use AspectJ and ClassA is a bean.

Comment: @Stultuske So i have to override this methods in every class that extends ClassB and pointcut has to point to every class that does so? If not can you please write how this pointcut should look like?

Comment: If you really use AspectJ (e.g. via load-time weaving configuration) and not Spring AOP, it works as you wish. If it does not work, you are not using AspectJ. It is as simple as that. If you want to challenge my statement, just provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) incl. Maven POM and ideally on GitHub, so I can just clone and run the application, e.g. via Spring Boot. BTW, in order to make this work with POJOs you don't need Spring at all. I tested your code outside of Spring.

Comment: This doesn't work because Spring AOP, by default, is proxy based. Only method calls INTO an object will pass through the proxy. You are doing self-invocation from a super class, those don't pass thought the proxy hence no AOP. The only solution is to use full blown AspectJ if you want that (with either load- or compile timeweaving).

Comment: As you said i was not using AspectJ so methods used from inside of ClassA were not catched by aspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented:

> If you really use AspectJ (e.g. via load-time weaving configuration) and not Spring AOP, it works as you wish. If it does not work, you are not using AspectJ. It is as simple as that. If you want to challenge my statement, just provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) incl. Maven POM and ideally on GitHub, so I can just clone and run the application, e.g. via Spring Boot. BTW, in order to make this work with POJOs you don't need Spring at all. I tested your code outside of Spring.

In order to support my statement, here is my MCVE using POJOs + AspectJ:

**Base class (why ever abstract because there are no abstract methods):**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public abstract class ClassB {
  public String extendedClassMethod1(String testString, Integer testInteger) {
    return testString + " / " + testInteger.toString();
  }

  public String extendedClassMethod2(String testString, Integer testInteger) {
    return testString + " / " + testInteger.toString();
  }
}
```

**(Concrete) subclass:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ClassA extends ClassB {
  public void testMethod(String testString, Integer testInt) {
    extendedClassMethod1(testString, testInt);
    extendedClassMethod2(testString, testInt);
  }
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    classA.extendedClassMethod1("eleven", 11);
    classA.extendedClassMethod2("twenty-two", 22);
    classA.testMethod("thirty-three", 33);
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class AspectClass {
  @AfterReturning(
    value = "execution(* de.scrum_master.app.ClassB.*(..)) && args(testString, testInteger)",
    returning = "result"
  )
  public void aspectMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, String testString, Integer testInteger, String result) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    System.out.println("  testString = " + testString);
    System.out.println("  testInteger = " + testInteger);
    System.out.println("  result = " + result);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.ClassB.extendedClassMethod1(String, Integer))
  testString = eleven
  testInteger = 11
  result = eleven / 11
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.ClassB.extendedClassMethod2(String, Integer))
  testString = twenty-two
  testInteger = 22
  result = twenty-two / 22
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.ClassB.extendedClassMethod1(String, Integer))
  testString = thirty-three
  testInteger = 33
  result = thirty-three / 33
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.ClassB.extendedClassMethod2(String, Integer))
  testString = thirty-three
  testInteger = 33
  result = thirty-three / 33
```